# @coffee_hour = Plan.find_by_event(:coffee_hour) ...Is it possible to link using a variable like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, class-instance-variables

My Links table has five different events and I use partials because they are scattered around the page. As an examples, "coffee_hour", and "wine_time." Each event has a url and a time. In my controller I have:

```
 @coffee = Link.find_by(event: "coffee")
 @wine = Link.find_by(event: "wine")
```

And my partials look something like this:

```
  <p>Join us for a cup of coffee... <%= link_to "by clicking here.", coffee.url %> ...</p>
```

and on my home page the code:

```
  <%= render partial: "links/coffee", locals: { coffee: @coffee } %>
```

There are separate partials for all five event types. But thee above results in "unidentified method 'url' for nil Nil:Class.  When I insert the phrase collection: @links, before locals, I don't get an error, but also nothing is returned. My code works in the console, but my Rails syntax must be off. Code in console:

```
  @coffee = Link.find_by(event: "coffee")
  @coffee.url # => correct url
```

Comment: Have you checked the correct template is being render for the action you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your controller code. Change it to this:

```
@coffee = Link.find_by(event: ‘coffee’)
@wine = Link.find_by(event: ‘wine’)
```

You can see, currently, you have parens around just the strings. You either need the parens around `event: string` or remove the parens altogether.

Comment: Edited question to reflect my correct code. Problem persists (but, again, this works in the console!

Comment: Remove the space between find_by and the opening parens in tour controller code.

Comment: Darn. That was a typo that was not in my code. Fixed question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally learned that my problem was I didn't have anything under def index in the links controller. putting

```
  @links = Link.all
```

solved the issue for me. Dumb mistake. Thanks all.